# Base Activity doesnt get API response in onTaskComplete

Tags: android, android-asynctask, httpresponse, android-actionbaractivity, asynctaskloader

I am currently facing problem in my project, where I am using an `abstract base activity` which extends `ActionBarActivity` and implements `AsyncTaskCompleteListener`. 
So there should be `onTaskCompleteListener`.

There it is, but the problem is that there is no `super.onTaskCompleteListener` which is unusual I think. I can make successful API calls (Volley HTTP request) but the `onTaskCompleteListener` isn't called. So I am not able to get the response data which I need for later process.

Why isn't the `super.onTaskCompleteListener` called?

Badly in need of help!! TIA

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Did u register _onTaskCompleteListener_?

Comment: public void onTaskCompleted(String response, int serviceCode) {

switch (serviceCode){
            case AndyConstants.ServiceCode.REQUEST:
        break ;
}

Comment: so are you calling _onTaskCompleteListener(this)_

Comment: no... isn't it supposed to be called when the activity makes API calls? sorry for late reply